# How to use Zend_Validate_File_MimeType()?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-validate

I´m trying to use the zend mime validator and I´m doing this:

```
$mime = array('image/jpeg','image/gif');
$valid = new Zend_Validate_File_MimeType($mime);
if ($valid->isValid($_FILES['file']['name']){
// do some stuff
}
```

But it not working, the documentation is weak, how can I use it??! THanks and best regard´s!

Comment: Can you define not working? Throws exception? Script dies? Kittens get killed? :)

Comment: Right it shoudl work with just the file name. Are you sure the file is uploaded ok? If you var_dump $_FILE do you get something?

Comment: I posted like this because I thought should use Zend_File or something similar to It. It´s correct, the form has enctype multipart and I just can´t do the validation. Should I use name ou type for the $_FILES variable?? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $valid->getMessages() to find out what happened

```
if ($valid->isValid($_FILES['file']['name']){
// do some stuff
} else {
$messages = $valid->getMessages();
print_r($messages);
}
//do the normal stuff
```

Comment: Should I use it with try catch? Thanks.

Comment: No, it's not an exception, an if else statement will do fine

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will try it and see what´s happening. Thanks again.